# Tikz scale vs pgf scale

Tags: tikz-pgf

The following code shows that the tikz "scale" is different from pgf?

Changing the scale values for x and y in the tikzset command will scale the tikz rectangle but not the pgf star. Any ideas how to reconcile this? I need to be able to to scale my tikz pictures easily but have pgf use the same scale and origin.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.callouts,shapes.geometric}
\begin{document}
\tikzset{x=0.1in,y=0.1in}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[top color= black!50] (-2,-2) rectangle (5,4);

\begin{scope}
\pgfset{minimum width=1.5cm,minimum height=1.5cm}
\pgftransformshift{\pgfpoint{2cm}{2cm}}
\pgfnode{star}{center}{}{}{\pgfusepath{clip}}
\pgftransformreset
% Back to drawing
\fill[yellow] (2cm,2cm) circle (0.65cm);
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You can try   `\makeatletter
  \pgfsys@transformxyscale{2}{2}`

Comment: that seems to work!

Comment: unfortunately that does not scale the node text by itself...

Comment: Your star is a node.  Generally, nodes don't scale with TikZ - you have to explicitly tell them to do so.  You're mixing TikZ and PGF commands which might mess things up a little, though, so there might be more to it than that.  If you used pure TikZ I'd say you should put the `transform shape` key on the node command.

Comment: @AndrewStacey Ok, that works. Another problem now is that my tikzpictures do not all have the same scale. The first one is larger than the others on these same page. I had no scaling issues using tikzset.

Comment: I'd need to see the new code to have a chance at guessing why that is so.

Comment: @AndrewStacey The code is to complex to post and make any real sense. There is just something funky going on when trying to mix tikz and pgf. I really don't need pgf except for clipping it seems but when trying to implement that it causes more problems than it's worth.

Comment: If you really want to scale _everything_ in the picture, you can always use `\scalebox{factor}{your tikzpicture here}`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The main difficulty is that the `scale` and `transform shape` keys belong to `/tikz/` family and does not penetrate down to PGF level. Instead they are mapped with rather tedious mechanisms. Hence, we need to somewhat fake it with low level transformation commands. If for some reasons we still need to use `[x=0.1in,y=0.1in]` we have to add the corresponding `\pgfsetxvec` and `\pgfsetyvec` commands appropriately to mimic the TikZ effect.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.75]
\pgfgettransform{\somemacro}
\draw[top color= black!50] (-2cm,-2cm) rectangle (5cm,4cm);
\draw[style=help lines] (-2cm,-2cm) grid[step=1cm] (5cm,4cm);
\node (o) at (0,0) {0};


\begin{scope}
\pgfset{minimum width=1.5cm,minimum height=1.5cm}
\pgftransformshift{\pgfpoint{3cm}{0cm}}
\pgfnode{star}{center}{}{}{\pgfusepath{clip}}
\pgfsettransform{\somemacro}
\fill[yellow] (3cm,0cm) circle (0.65cm);
\end{scope}

\node[draw,circle,transform shape] (dum) at (2,2) {(2,2)};

\begin{scope}
\pgfset{minimum width=2cm,minimum height=2cm}
\pgftransformshift{\pgfpoint{0cm}{2.5cm}}
\pgfnode{star}{center}{}{}{\pgfusepath{clip}}
\pgfsettransform{\somemacro}
\fill[red] (0cm,2.5cm) circle (0.8cm);
\end{scope}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I'm still having issues with the scaling. Add/modify your code to use `\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.35, transform shape]
\tikzset{x=1in,y=1in}
\makeatletter\pgfsys@transformxyscale{0.35}{0.35}`... All I'm trying to do now is get the tikz scaling that I'm using to match with the pgf scaling.

Comment: If you do not use the tikzset line then the tikz scale in tikzpicture is not overridden by the pgf scale. It seems they are interacting insome weird or unexpected way. Also I guess I do not understand what the tikzset is actually doing... Seems like it is actually just shifting the origin than anything.

Comment: ok, what it seems like is some scale factor difference. I took out the scale factor from the tikzpicture and used only the makeat one. The scale factor then is applied globally and each new picture environment is scaled repeatedly(so each new picture is scaled down by another extra factor). Should be easy to fix by saving the transform and restoring. BUT all the pgf code in the setclip lua function seems to be using a different scaling factor as it maps to the data exactly if shrunk. This could have to do with the dimension/units issue.

Comment: The problem is, I can't seem to scale just one or the other to get them to match. I think it is the pgfsys transform that I'm using as it is messing up tikz. (I might need to use it outside the tikz frame or calculate my own scaling factors instead of using it in setclip)

Comment: Multiplying the pgf coordinates(the x and y in setclip) by 1/2.54 fixes the problem. I guess the pgf dimensions are in cm by default and I'm using inches in my tikz code. (since my engineering drawings are in inches) This gets everything aligned and properly clipped like it is suppose to be. I'll have to play around with it some more to see if anything else is broken but it looks right so far.

Comment: @Uiy That's good to hear :P. If you want to set the pgf units as you do with `[x=...,y=...]`, I have given the equivalent low level commands above. That way you can change the unit vectors to inches if you like e.g. `\pgfsetxvec{\pgfpoint{1in}{0}}` sets the x vector to be `(1in,0)`. But the placement of the command is also important. After the transform and before the transform matters.

Comment: I'm not sure if it works but knowing that it was simply an issue with units and that I can scale myself give some relief. I've tried the set?vec and it doesn't seem to work but probably used in the wrong place(I used it where I set tikz to use inches).

Comment: @Uiy Just let me know in the chat room if things get ugly and we can have a look again. I know it's frustrating but it's only us that can adapt to TikZ and not the other way around (For now that is :)

Comment: Well, I think I've got just about everything I needed except for regions stuff. Not sure if that will ever get done but at this point everything else seems to work the way I want it.