# How to incorporate and scale matplotlib plots in latex using the PGF backend?

Tags: tikz-pgf, matplotlib, tikzscale

I am using the pgf backend of matplotlib to generate pgf files which I want to put into my latex document using tikzscale to be able to resize them easily.

Example python code:

```python
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import matplotlib as mpl
mpl.use('pgf')
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as mplp

mpl.rcParams['text.latex.unicode']=True
mpl.rcParams['text.usetex']=True
mpl.rcParams['pgf.texsystem'] = 'pdflatex'

fig = mplp.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

x = np.arange(0,2 * np.pi, .1)
data = np.sin(x)

fmt = {"lw" : 3, "c" : "r", "ls" : '-'}

ax.plot(x, data, label=r"sample data with greek $\mu$", **fmt)

ax.set_ylabel(r"sample", rotation=0)
ax.legend()
fig.set_size_inches(1.41,1.)
# fig.savefig('./sample.pgf', dpi=500, bbox_inches='tight')
fig.savefig('./sample.pgf', dpi=500)
```

Example latex code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikzscale}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\pgfplotsset{compat=1.8}

\newcommand{\includepgf}[4]
{
  \begin{figure}
  \centering
  \includegraphics{#1}
  \includegraphics[width=#2\textwidth, height=#2*0.7071428571428572\textwidth]{#1}
  \includegraphics[width=#2\textwidth, axisratio=0.7071428571428572]{#1}
  \caption[]{#4}
  \label{#3}
  \end{figure}
}

\begin{document}
\includepgf{sample.pgf}{.9}{fig:sample}{Sample Figure}    
\end{document}
```

Unfortunately the following happens for the three different `\includegraphics` commands:

1. Works as expected, includes plot in original size
2. Compiles with

   ```
    Package tikzscale Warning: Scaling of sample.pgf's width was only
    (tikzscale)                accurate to 208.59694pt on input line 27.


    Package tikzscale Warning: Scaling of sample.pgf's height was only
    (tikzscale)                accurate to 147.29488pt on input line 27.
   ```

   no resizing in final pdf file.
3. Does not compile, gives

   ```
    ! Package tikzscale Error: Requested to scale unscalable graphic.
   ```

Comment: Nils: If I were to take a wild guess, then I'd say that `tikzscale` perhaps doesn't work with `pgfpicture`s. Workarounds could be to generate different `.pgf` files, with different values in `fig.set_size_inches`, or create a PDF by `input`ing `sample.pgf` in a separate `.tex` file and including that PDF with `includegraphics`.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. You're probably right, the error messages seem pretty fundamental. Your workaround is viable, but it destroys the point in using the pgf backend, i.e. to have perfectly matched font sizes, colors, fonts, etc. I was under the impression that this is one of the main reasons the pgf backend was introduced.

Comment: Well, my first suggestion doesn't have that issue. The only problem there is that you have to know what size you want for the figure beforehand. You could take a look at using [`matplotlib2tikz`](https://github.com/nschloe/matplotlib2tikz), which spits out `pgfplots` code. `tikzscale` should work with `pgfplots` plots according to the manual.

Comment: You're right, it would not destroy the point of using the backend. It would just introduce a restriction which can be annoying if I need to use the plot in a different layout. Ill look into `matplotlib2tikz`, thank you!

Comment: Ok, I tried `matplotlib2tikz`, it has its issues. Legends to not work as expected, errorbar plots do not work, etc. It seems, that there really is no perfect way of creating plots in matplotlib and use them in latex. I very much anticipate the need of using my plots in slides, on posters and in journal documents, which will all have very different layouts. Seems i'll be forced to redo my pgf files each time.

Comment: Sorry for resurrecting, but couldn't Torbjørn's suggestion of putting everything inside a .tex work if the pgf is embedded into a tex file, then included directly into the main latex document WITHOUT manually creating a pdf?

Comment: Do I create an intermediary pdf file in the above code? I was under the impression, that using includegraphics on a pgf wouldnt do that, but would just use pgfplots to create the graphic.

Comment: Some related questions: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/148296/ http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/53605/ Alains suggestion from a comment, `\makeatletter\pgfsys@transformxyscale{2}{2}\makeatother`, will let you scale the `pgf`-image, but the text will be scaled as well, so it's not really a solution.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

I don't think `includegraphics` is the natural solution since you are creating a usable LaTeX file.  As @Torbjørn T. has already mentioned, you should use the `input` command.  Then, to solve your scaling problem, you might use

```
\scalebox{1.5}{\input{sample.pgf}}
```

for example; there is no preliminary LaTeX compilation involved.

- In case you want to use `includegraphics`, it is natural to save your image as a `png` file in `python`.
- Looking at the output of the `python` code, the `pgf` file, it seems to me that there are some cropping issues.

**The code**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikzscale}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]

\begin{figure}[htb!]
  \centering
  \scalebox{.5}{\input{sample.pgf}}
  \scalebox{1}{\input{sample.pgf}}
  \scalebox{1.5}{\input{sample.pgf}}
  \caption{Sample figure modified with scalebox}
  \label{fig:1}
\end{figure}

\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```